# Python If statement ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm having a problem in my python procedure that makes an adjacency list. The list itself is working properly, but then the program will see if there is a path between va and vb(a to b). The problem is the if statements are completely ignored even after messing around with tuples and brackets as well. The if should verify if there is a path, and if there is send a message. If there is no path, then a variable will be incremented until the loop ends. If it ends without a path being found, there is a failure message.
Here is the code:
grafo is a graph type.

```
class graph:
  v = 0
  a = 0
  node = []

class vertex:
  ta = []
  adj = {}

def caminhografo(grafo, va, vb):
  vat = defaultdict(list)
  i = 0
  a = 0
  z = 0
  vo = int(va)
  vq = int(vb)
  vz = int(va)
  vw = int(vb)
  x = len(grafo.node)
  if vz < vw:
      for vz in range (vw+1):
          a = 0
          x = len(grafo.node)
          for a in range (x):
              if [int(vz),int(a)] in grafo.node:
                  vat[vz].append(a)                   
  if vz > vw:
      while vz > vw:
          a = 0
          x = len(grafo.node)
          for a in range (x):
              if[int(va),int(a)] in grafo.node:
                  vat[vz].append(a)
          vz = vz - 1
  a = 0
  x = len(grafo.node)
  print(vat)
  z = 0
  #Problem starts here, after adjacency list is complete, none of the if's work and     There is never a path between vertex.
  for z in range (x):
      if (vo,vq) in vat:
         print("""
  ==============================================
           Existe Caminho
  ==============================================
  """)
         break
      elif (vo,z) in vat:
          vo = z

  print("""
  ==============================================
   Não Existe Caminho
  ==============================================
  "")
```

So if i send va and vb as 0 and 1 after inserting an arc between vertex 0 and 1, the output shows (0:[1],1:[0]). Which means there is path between these vertex. Except the if in the end, that is supposed to verify a path, never succeeds.

I'm also using defaultdict, the adjacency list is a dictionary of lists from defaultdict.
The final output is always ("Não existe Caminho"),("No Path"), which is the final print.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code so it appears the way you see it in your editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statemnts are looking for tuples in your dictionary. They're not going to find them though, because your dictionary uses single values as keys.

I think you want your check to be:

```
if vo in vat and vq in vat[vo]:
```

The first of those checks isn't even strictly required, since `vat` is a `defaultdict` (but it will help avoid unneeded empty lists being added).

There may still be some other issues though. I don't really understand what your `z` loop or the `elif` block is supposed to be doing. Furthermore, your `"Não Existe Caminho"` text will always be displayed, even if a path is found.